# memset sets some elements to *almost* zero or nan

Tags: c, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the line `memset(C, 0, N*M);`, where C is a matrix of doubles. (I am using WSL.)

However if I look in gdb, certain elements in the matrix are set to either `-nan(0xffffffffffff8)` and others are set to for example `9.0096750001652956e-314`.

The first one doesn't give any errors but a `+=` doesn't seem to change anything (or at the very least doesn't seem to make the nan thing disappear), while the second is an issue if the element is not changed or only has `+= 0`, as the comparison `if (0 == C[i][j])` then fails.

If I set the values to 0 manually, then these issues do not arise at all.

Is this a WSL thing, or is there something about `memset` that I do not understand?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: How is `C` defined? Is it `double C[M][N)`?  Then you only set 1/8 of the memory to 0.

Comment: memset is very close to the hardware, it doesn't do anything except setting every single bit in the floating point representation to zero.

Comment: My guess is that you should use `memset(C,0,N*M*sizeof(type))`...

Comment: @Laci: safer to write ` memset(C, 0, sizeof(type) * N * M)` to avoid potential overflow on `N * M`.

Comment: `double C[M][N] = {0};` would be an option if you only set them to 0 when `C` is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `M*N` is the number of *items* (doubles) but `memset` expects the number of *bytes*. For an array `double C[M][N]`, you need to do `memset(C, 0, sizeof(C));`.

Comment: `C` could be a pointer as in `clear_matrix(double C[N][M])`

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, but the answer says to use `sizeof(C)` "For an array `double C[M][N]`"

Comment: @ikegami: I know, but Lundin did not post a code sample and some pointer declarations look confusingly similar to arrays.

Comment: To clarify, there are two situations where arrays "decay", either when used in any expression _except_ when the expression is the operators `&` or `sizeof`. Or when declared as a function parameter. This would be the former case and it _is_ the operand of `sizeof`.

Comment: Perhaps write it as "For an array `double C[M][N]` that is not a function parameter" to make it clear that it really is an array.

Answer (score 5):

You do not fully initialize the matrix: `memset()` expects a number of bytes. Assuming the matrix layout is linear, either 1D or 2D, you should clear `sizeof(double) * N * M` bytes.

If your matrix is defined as a 2D array, you could write:

```
#define N 10
#define M 20
        double C[N][M];
        memset(C, 0, sizeof C);
```

If the matrix is received as a function argument, you actually get a pointer, so you must be more careful:

```
void clear_matrix(double C[N][M]) {
    memset(C, 0, sizeof(*C) * N);
}
```

or possibly more readable:

```
void clear_matrix(double C[N][M]) {
    memset(C, 0, sizeof(C[0][0]) * N * M);
}
```

or simply, as suggested by Lundin, but likely to break if the matrix element type changes:

```
void clear_matrix(double C[N][M]) {
    memset(C, 0, sizeof(double[N][M]);
}
```

Note however that `memset()` will clear the matrix data to all bits zero, which sets the `double` values to `+0.0` if the system uses IEEE-754 representation, but is not fully portable. A portable version would use a nested loop and a [good compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6bncc3rd) will generate the same `memset` call or inline code if appropriate for the target system:

```
#include <stddef.h>

#define N 10
#define M 20

void clear_matrix(double C[N][M]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < M; j++) {
             C[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A third, even less confusing alternative: `sizeof( double[N][M] )`.

Comment: @Lundin: yes, less confusing but more error prone :)

Comment: That argument doesn't hold well for 2D arrays. Take for example `double (*arr)[X][Y] = malloc(sizeof *arr)` versus `double (*arr)[Y] = malloc(X * sizeof *arr);`. This is about as error prone as it gets IMO. For some `double C[N][M])` parameter, I would be very temped to `C = malloc(sizeof *C);`. Oops.